# サービスアカウントの認証

Tags: google-cloud, google-drive-sdk

Google Cloud SDK でサービスアカウントのアクティベートを実行しようとしたところ以下のエラーが表示されています。

> ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Unable to read file
> [./credential.json]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> './credential.json'

Key_file の格納場所が相違しているのか原因がわからず、対応方法についてご教示いただけますと幸いです。
下記に全文を記載します。
※他社経由で吐き出したGCSアカウントのため、コンソールは使用できずgsutilでの設定を試行しております

※参照しているマニュアル
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account

```
C:\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud auth list
         Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
        xxxx@example.co.jp

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`


C:\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud config set account dp-xxxx@xxxx-service-account-2.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Updated property [core/account].

C:\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud auth list
         Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
        xxxx@example.co.jp

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`


C:\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud auth activate-service-account dp-xxxx@xxxx-service-account-2.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file ./credential.json --project xxxx-per-client
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Unable to read file [./credential.json]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './credential.json'
```

Comment: コマンドを実行したフォルダに credential.json ファイルは存在しますか？

Comment: 以下配下にjsonファイル（Key_file）を格納しています...　　　C:\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>

Answer (score 0):

こちらjsonファイル名を変更したところ実行できました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: 具体的にはどのように変更することで解決しましたか？一見すると質問に記載されたファイル名も問題が無さそうに見えたので、違いが分かるように回答もまとめてあると、同じような問題で困った人の助けになると思います。